# IDA Pro variable declaration

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I'm quite new to x86 assembly and reverse engineering and have a question about this piece of code I obtained through IDA:

```
; LRESULT __stdcall WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR)
WndProc proc near

Rect= tagRECT ptr -34h
var_24= dword ptr -24h
var_20= dword ptr -20h
var_1C= dword ptr -1Ch
var_18= dword ptr -18h
prc= RECT ptr -14h
var_4= dword ptr -4
hWnd= dword ptr  8
uMsg= dword ptr  0Ch
wParam= dword ptr  10h
lParam= dword ptr  14h
```

Am I correct that var_18, var_1C and var_20 are actually pointing to prc.top, prc.right and prc.bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; if `prc` is a `RECT` instance then it occupies the *following* 16 bytes of memory (so offset -14 through -5 inclusive, four 32-bit words).

Comment: Ah now I see. var_24 is actually of type RECT. A litle bit further in the code there is a call to GetWindowRect and var_24 as the RECT to fill with the dimensions. So, var_18, var_1C and var_20 are pointing to the var_24 top, right and bottom members then?

Comment: @Jelle: double-click the declaration of `var_24` to open the stack frame view, press Alt-Q, select `RECT` from the structures list. It will turn those four variables into a single one with the right type, just like `prc`.